# What format should the Y in sklearn be?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does `Y` have to be one-hot encoded or not? For example in this code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Comment: You can see an example here. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Answer (score 1):

Y should be one column of your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

No, `y` should usually not be one-hot encoded.

In general, one-hot encoding or dummy encoding is used to encode **features** (columns in `X`), not the target `y`.

In machine learning tasks, `y` is very often a single column from your data, represented as a 1d array, a list, or a Pandas `Series`. Notice the example in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html):

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

`y` is usually written with a lower-case letter (though not always, as you see above), because conventional mathematical notation uses upper-case letters like `X` for matrices (often represented as 2d arrays in NumPy, or as a `DataFrame` in Pandas), and lower-case for *vectors* (1d arrays or `Series` in Pandas).